# Test ownership in a helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this block in my views:

```
<% video.members.each do |p| %>
  <% if p.id == current_user.id %>
    <%= "paid" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Basically I'm trying to work out if a member has paid for a video based on whether the id's match.

Maybe this a really bad way of doing it, which case I'd be happy to try and different method.

Assuming it is an ok way of checking this, **how could I write a similar statement but as a helper method?**  I've tried, but it seems you can't write the same logic in helpers as the block just spits out the full array and not the id, meaning it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do this instead:

```
<% if video.members.exists?(id: current_user.id) %>
  <%= 'Paid' %>
<% end %>
```

This will generate a single query to test if the video has been paid by the current_user ;-)

---

**In a helper:**

```
# application_helper.rb
def display_paid_or_not(video)
  return '' if video.blank? # similar to .nil?
  video.members.exists?(id: current_user.id) ? 'Paid' : ''
end

# in view
<%= display_paid_or_not(video) %>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Amazing, thanks MrYoshiji, just what I needed, works perfectly